# Delete all mesh parts that can not be seen from outside

Tags: mesh

I have a mesh that resembles a miniature and is supposed to be 3D-printed. It seems like it was created in a 'messy' way because many parts of the mesh grow inside and create cavities causing the prints to fail. All the vertices of the mesh are connected and I am trying to find a way to get rid of all the internal mesh parts.

It sounds so easy to delete every vertice that can not be reached by a ray from the outside through the faces of the mesh but I just can't find a solution.

In theory I could probably select all vertices in edit mode form one side and repeating that from all possible angles until I have all vertices selected that can be seen from the outside. But that is not practical since the model has over a million vertices and many small details and bulges that make it unfeasible to get even close to selecting all the vertices even when I decimate the model first. And since there are so many vertices and operating inside the model with the camera is very hard I also gave up on deleting every unwanted vertice by hand.

All answers I found online from selecting non-manifolds to hollowing, solidifying, extruding, remeshing or scaling the model down to hollow out a duplicate with it did not work.

Any new suggestions would be highly appreciated.